# comparing string in a column and creating respective a new column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have data frame as shown below. I need to compare column in a data frame with the string and creating a new column.

DataFrame:

```
col_1
AB_SUMI
AK_SUMI
SB_LIMA
SB_SUMI
XY_SUMI
```

If 'AB','AK','SB' are present in col_1 it should create a new column with their respective values otherwise '*' should come in the column value.

expected output:

```
col_1      new_col
AB_SUMI     AB
AK_SUMI     AK
SB_LIMA     SB
SB_SUMI     SB
XY_SUMI     *
```

I have tried with below code but not worked out.

```
list=['AB','AK','AB']

for item in list:
    if df['col1'].str.contains(item).any():
        df['new']=item
```

please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `regex` created with `list` by `join` `|` (`or`), last replace `NaN` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
L= ['AB','AK','SB']
a = '(' + '|'.join(L) + ')'
print (a)
(AB|AK|SB)

df['new'] = df.col_1.str.extract(a, expand=False).fillna('*')
print (df)
     col_1 new
0  AB_SUMI  AB
1  AK_SUMI  AK
2  SB_LIMA  SB
3  SB_SUMI  SB
4  XY_SUMI   *
```

Comment: That's creative!

Comment: One more doubt, if I want to change new column values with all conditions, remain same what changes should I make in above code?

Comment: I am not sure if understand - what conditions? Can you explain more?

Comment: I want to change new col values expected output. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you think existing column? then use same way as answer `df['col_1'] = df.col_1.str.extract(a, expand=False).fillna('*')`

Comment: maybe help me if give me a example with desired output, still not clear for me, sorry :(

Comment: I need expected output as mentioned above

Comment: I need expected output as mentioned below
`df_output={'col_1':['AB_SUMI', ' AK_SUMI ','SB_LIMA','SB_SUMI','XY_SUMI'], 'new' : ['AB_1','AK_1','SB_1','SB_1',' * ' ]}`

Comment: Then only add `_1` - `df['new'] = df.col_1.str.extract(a, expand=False).add('_1').fillna('*')`

Answer (score 0):

A fun approach

```
L = 'AB AK SB'.split()

c = df.col_1.values.astype(str)
f = lambda x, s : np.core.defchararray.find(x, s) >= 0
df.assign(new=np.stack([f(c, i) for i in L]).astype(object).T.dot(np.reshape(L, (-1, 1)))).replace('', '*')

     col_1 new
0  AB_SUMI  AB
1  AK_SUMI  AK
2  SB_LIMA  SB
3  SB_SUMI  SB
4  XY_SUMI   *
```