# Problematic values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a 'Trousers' column containing many different types of trousers.  Most of the trousers would start by their type. For instance: Jeans- Replay-blue, or Chino- Uniqlo-~, or maybe Smart-Next-~). Others would just have a type but just a long name (2 or 3 strings)
What I want is to loop through that column to change the values to just Jean **if jeans is in the cell**,or  **Chinos if Chino is in the cell** and so on.... so I can easily group them.

How can achieve that through with my for loop?

Comment: please post raw data, code to create your df, your attempts and the desired output. Basically this can be done but you need to clarify further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then select first value of lists by `str[0]`:

```
df['type'] = df['Trousers'].str.split('-').str[0]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Trousers':['Jeans- Replay-blue','Chino- Uniqlo-~','Smart-Next-~']})
print (df)
             Trousers
0  Jeans- Replay-blue
1     Chino- Uniqlo-~
2        Smart-Next-~

df['type'] = df['Trousers'].str.split('-').str[0]
print (df)
             Trousers   type
0  Jeans- Replay-blue  Jeans
1     Chino- Uniqlo-~  Chino
2        Smart-Next-~  Smart
```

---

```
df['Trousers'] = df['Trousers'].str.split('-').str[0]
print (df)
  Trousers
0    Jeans
1    Chino
2    Smart
```

Another solution with [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Trousers'] = df['Trousers'].str.extract('([a-zA-z]+)-', expand=False)
print (df)
  Trousers
0    Jeans
1    Chino
2    Smart
```

Comment: Thanks again. But I am kinda running into the same problem as all trousers do not start by their 'type'+ '-'.  A loop would be great so that I do not have 2 or 3 classification columns.

Comment: Can you edit question with problematic values? Thanks.

Comment: I think can you get list of values, where this solution cannot be used? Sorry, maybe my explanation was not clear.

Comment: If is possible create list with all possible type, then use [extract](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42883430/2901002) - then is not necessary it type is in first place.